# Is it possible to limit the file extension in anchors <a> HTML 5 download attribute?

Tags: javascript, download, electron, html5-canvas

**TLDR: When using anchor's HTML5 download attribute, it is possible to lock the file extension?**

Hello everyone,

I have a desktop application running in electron (javascript) that enables users to draw on top of a map and export the canvas to a file.
To do so, I convert the map canvas to a binary file and then create an anchor to trigger the download.
This can be done as following:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = 'map-canvas.jpg';
link.href = dataUrl; // this is the blob
link.click();
```

So far, so good. This will prompt the user to save the file, as shown bellow:
[image: download prompt]

However, the user may change the filename and accidentally remove the file extension. This can generate a problem, since the user won't be able to easily open the file.

Hence, is it possible to lock the file extension that the download specifies?

Comment: Why not send it to the `main` process and and use Node integration `fs` - then ask for a directory to put the file in - and write the file directly.?

Comment: This may answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253771/download-attribute-not-suggesting-file-extension-in-save-dialog

Comment: @Marcos - what browser did you actually tried this with? If I try to download a canvas blob from firefox, it pre-selects *.png for filetype.

Comment: @EfiShtainer this worked :-)